# Best alternative way to develop/test a facebook app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, testing

Due to the limitations of the current test users graph api, the bugged platform (e.g., I can't even log into my app as a test user right now) and the complete lack of feedback from facebook in the blog and in the forum, I'm pretty much stalled with the app development. I'm learning as I write so I need to constantly test the code to make sure it makes sense. The app I'm making relies on the interaction of several users at the same time, so it is not really feasible to use my own account (or, at least, ONLY my account).

**So, my question is: do you have a good alternative solution that does not break fb contract? (i.e., creating a bunch of regular, fake accounts is NOT a solution). How are you testing your app?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no other way to test besides using test accounts.  Everyone I know who develops for Facebook has several accounts just for testing.  I think if that's all you're using them for, and not trying to abuse the web site, they'll look past you breaking this particular rule (never heard of anyone getting busted for it).

Also, remember that not all Facebook features will work as expected when testing via localhost.  For this reason it's good to have a test server you can quickly and frequently deploy your app to.

Also (also), it also often helps to have two versions of the Facebook application created - prod and test.  This way you can play in a sandbox when it comes to updating/fixing the app, while it's already live and people expect no downtime.

Comment: I was afraid the answer would be that one. I was trying to avoid creating the fake accounts. That's the whole point of the test account api, right? I can deal with some limitations in the api, but the complete lack of support is what kills me. I'm working on localhost right now but it's a project to be deployed to the google app engine. As soon as I have finished my first draft of the app I'll start testing it from the google servers instead. Thanks for the tip of having two (prod and test) apps! That is a very good advice for a newbie like myself.

Comment: I waited a few days before accepting it, hoping somebody would come with another option, but it seems that really there is no other one...